# can we improve this code?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I need to pick the first result based on 3 checks which need to be executed in sequence. i.e if there is no object that meets criterion 1, then we look for any object meeting criterion 2 and so on. Here is my working code

```
MyClass result = myObjects.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.meetsCriterion1())
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            return myObjects.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.meetsCriterion2())
                .findFirst()
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    return myObjects.stream()
                        .filter(s -> s.meetsCriterion3())
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseGet(() -> {
                            return null;
                        });
                });
        });
```

can we improve this code? I am not sure if there is a way to reuse the first stream to evaluate all the criterion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. (also, the "optional" tag refers to the concept of optionals in programming)

Comment: @PWhite findFirst() returns an `Optional` and `orElseGet`is a method of the Optional class; therefore, the OP was correct to include the tag 'optional'.

Comment: Note that you don’t need to write `() -> { return expression; }`, a simple `() -> expression` is enough; that also applies to nested lambdas…

Answer (score 6):

I would separate the list of criteria from the logic:

```
List<Predicate<MyClass>> criteria = Arrays.asList(
    MyCass::meetsCriterion1,
    MyCass::meetsCriterion2,
    MyCass::meetsCriterion3
);


MyClass result = criteria.stream()
    .flatMap(c -> myObjects.stream().filter(c).limit(1))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);  // questionable.  consider redesigning to avoid null.
```

Comment: Nicely done. +1 for "consider redesigning to avoid null."